# Helvetica Neue Cyrillic Extended - design nightmare

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I am working on a website for a client and they want the text to show in Helvetica Neue. I have heard about this font a lot but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I mean I found the Latin one but not the Cyrillic one that has the letter Ү and Ө. Is there such a font? And where can I find it? The one looks like y is not y. :D

Comment: Is this not it ? http://www.linotype.com/109382/NeueHelveticaProCyrillic55Roman-product.html

Comment: I saw that but it does not have the 2 letters i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they want Helvetica Neue Cyrillic on a web page, they need to contact Linotype and ask for a quotation on a price for a license that permits such usage. I don’t think they will get one.

If they want just something similar, someone has to search for suitably similar fonts. “Something similar” might appear under a name like “Helvetica Neue” but only if it is not distributed commercially, as the name is protected by trade mark.

Comment: screw the clients i am using arial it looks similar enough XD

Comment: Or you could use e.g. the Google font Ubuntu and say that it is a free Helvetica-like font...: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Ubuntu

Comment: They probably don't know how font licensing works, so respectfully explain to them that they can't use commercial fonts without buying a license, so it doesn't happen again to you or other developers. Also, if you have more questions about Cyrillic or types you can ask in http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

while this is not a Programming question here is a link that can help you [Helvetica_Neue_](http://rghost.net/2222821) as well as ['helvetica neue cyrillic](http://www.abstractfonts.com/search/helvetica+neue+cyrillic)

Google is your friend

Comment: lol those links were like the first two to appear on my google search. I already downloaded and tested those fonts on your links and none had the letters i needed. thanks though